# Passing along *args, **kwargs to parent class after modification

Tags: python

Based on a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930630/grouping-an-unknown-number-of-arguments-with-argparse#34930706), I implemented the following modified `argparse.Action` which produces key-value pairs.

I want to allow `nargs` to be dynamically set, as well as provide the option to use a `defaultdict(list)` for cases where keys may appear more than once.

Here is the implementation I have:

```
import argparse
from collections import defaultdict

class NamespaceAction(argparse.Action):
    """
    This modified action allows me to group together key-value pairs passed to an argument.
    Extended to produce a defaultdict(list) if requested, so that a key can appear more than once.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.nargs = kwargs.get('nargs', 1)
        self.mode = kwargs.get('mode', 'dict')  # default mode is dict
        super(NamespaceAction, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        # The default value is often set to None rather than an empty list.
        current_arg_vals = getattr(namespace, self.dest, []) or []
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, current_arg_vals)
        arg_vals = getattr(namespace, self.dest)
        try:
            if self.mode == 'dict':
                arg_vals.append(argparse.Namespace(**dict(v.split('=') for v in values)))
            elif self.mode == 'defaultdict':
                d = defaultdict(list)
                for v in values:
                    v = v.split('=')
                    d[v[0]].append(v[1])
                arg_vals.append(argparse.Namespace(**d))
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError("only dict or defaultdict")
        except TypeError:
            raise RuntimeError('Group {} appears to be incorrectly formatted'.format(values))
```

However, using this leads to `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'`. However, if I delete `mode` and `dict` from args/kwargs, it still does not work:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.nargs = kwargs.get('nargs', 1)
    self.mode = kwargs.get('mode', 'dict')  # default mode is dict
    if 'mode' in kwargs:
        del kwargs['mode']
    if 'nargs' in kwargs:
        del kwargs['nargs']
    super(NamespaceAction, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Leads to `TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)`.

How can I go about having this class take arguments, and still properly have the parent initialized?

Comment: Given that `Action.__init__` takes two positional arguments, `option_strings` and `dest`, it seems like a bad idea, if not just wrong, to assume the first positional argument to `NamespaceAction` is the number of arguments.

Comment: True, I can change that to be another keyword argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting `nargs` to be positional, but it's an optional argument to [`argparse.Action`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Action); per the docs:

> The Action class must accept the two positional arguments plus any keyword arguments passed to `ArgumentParser.add_argument()` except for the `action` itself.

You might try:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # To force nargs, look it up, but don't bother setting on self;
    # just let it pass to the parent, if you remove it from kwargs, the
    # parent __init__ overwrites self.nargs with None
    nargs = kwargs['nargs'] 
    assert isinstance(nargs, int) or nargs == "+"
    # dict.pop is like get, but removes the mapping if it exists
    self.mode = kwargs.pop('mode', 'dict')  # Will use 'dict' as default

    # Pass along remaining arguments
    super(NamespaceAction, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That still leads to the error `TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)`.

Comment: Nevermind, I was using it wrong. I need to use kwargs in `add_argument`, and not do `action=NamespaceAction()`

Comment: @IanFiddes: Are you sure? I can't reproduce. I do see one flaw (you're intercepting the `nargs` argument, so the `repr` of the object says it's `None`, even when passed, because the default argument on parent `__init__` overrides it; you could just ignore `nargs` and let the parent class `__init__` handle it, then check to make sure `self.nargs` is non-`None` afterwards), but it otherwise works fine when I do `parser.add_argument('foo', action=NamespaceAction, nargs=12)`, which is where `NamespaceAction.__init__` is invoked. Is the traceback showing you a problem in `__init__` of your code?

Comment: @IanFiddes: Yeah, it should be `action=NamespaceAction`, no parens. Glad you figured it out.